# ColdFusion Builder and Remote ColdFusion Server

Tags: coldfusion, rds, coldfusionbuilder

My workstation (Windows 7) has CF Builder 3 installed. Remote is CF 2016 Server. What I'd like to accomplish is download the CF source files to local hard drive and use full CF Builder tools like Breakpoints to work with the remote CF Server. I can't install a local CF Server because I am unable to create datasources locally.

Is it even possible to accomplish the setup in my scenario? Here is a site which lists some options: http://csis.pace.edu/~ctappert/cs615-02/support/Help/Using_ColdFusion_Studio/mapping3.htm but none of them fits my needs. I think the best I could accomplish, then, would be to create a subfolder in the remote CF Server site, copy source code to that, and make CF Builder work with the code sitting on the server.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,

I ended up working off CFM files on the remote CF Server using Network share; it's slow and I am unable to hit Breakpoints in Debugging in CF Studio but at least I am able to make the CFM code to run on the remote server.

Thanks.